# Tag synonyms for the Moon

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have three tags that should be synonyms: [moon](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moon), [the-moon](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-moon), and [lunar](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lunar). Tags related to the Sun ([the-sun](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-sun) and [solar](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar)) have been marked as synonyms of [sun](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sun), which is the master tag for this group. In keeping with this, tag:moon should be the master tag for questions related to the Moon.

There are a number problems with this, however. The correct tag for the Sun should be Sun rather than sun, and for the Moon, Moon rather than moon. This is not possible as SE tags are lowercased. Related to this is that there's a big difference between a moon (with a lowercase m) and the Moon (with an uppercase M). Despite the verbiage, there are already some questions tagged as "moon" that pertain to moons other than the Moon.

Another problem is that the tag "the-moon" has many more questions (247) than do the tags "moon" (32 questions) and "lunar" (10 questions). Making "moon" the master (without a capital M) will invite continued mis-tagging.

My proposal:

1. Make "the-moon" the master tag for questions pertaining to the Moon.
2. Make "lunar" tag a synonym of "the-moon".
3. Add a new tag "moons", a synonym of "natural-satellite", and retag the few questions tagged as "moon" that don't belong in that category as  "moons".
4. Retag as "the-moon" all the remaining questions tagged as "moon" that do indeed pertain to the Moon.
5. Lock the tag "moon" as ambiguous given the lowercase nature of SE tags.

I can't do the retagging presently; work beckons. I can undertake this effort later this evening, about 12 to 13 hours from now.

Comment: [tag:the-sun] and [tag:the-moon] are now the official tags. [tag:lunar] is now a synonym of [tag:the-moon]. [tag:moons] is now a synonym of [tag:natural-satellite]. Only developers can blacklist tags, but I don't think we need to blacklist [tag:moon]. I made it a synonym of [tag:the-moon]. Even though [tag:moon] is ambiguous, in most cases people will be looking for [tag:the-moon]. When they are not, they will see that they have not used the correct tag and can either look for another or seek assistance.

Comment: I have not done any retagging, so folks will want to keep their eyes out for Qs that need retagging.

Comment: I just retagged a bunch of questions that were tagged with [tag:the-moon], but just the obvious ones asking about moons of Venus (or lack thereof), Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Neptune, Uranus, Pluto, exoplanets, etc.

Comment: @called2voyage - Just to finalize this, make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[the-sun](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-sun) and [the-moon](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-moon) are now the official tags. [lunar](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lunar) is now a synonym of [the-moon](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-moon). [moons](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moons) is now a synonym of [natural-satellite](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-satellite). Only developers can blacklist tags, but I don't think we need to blacklist [moon](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moon). I made it a synonym of [the-moon](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-moon). Even though [moon](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moon) is ambiguous, in most cases people will be looking for [the-moon](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-moon). When they are not, they will see that they have not used the correct tag and can either look for another or seek assistance.

I have not done any retagging, so folks will want to keep their eyes out for Qs that need retagging.